# How do I unlock a client running Windows XP through Synergy?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, synergy, windows-domain

I asked this question on the Synergy OSQA site, but I haven't had any responses. Forgive me if you've already seen it.

I have a Synergy server running Windows 7 SP1. I have one client running Windows XP SP3. Both are joined to a domain, which requires that <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> be pressed prior to logging in. I've read that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> should unlock it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Is there another way I can unlock the client, or something I need to configure?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  Server and client are both Win7 and Synergy is running as a service on both.  No response on the client from CTRL+ALT+Pause/Break

Answer (score 0):

The key combination to unlock a client is Ctrl + Alt + Break. If the machine has just rebooted, the client needs to have Synergy running as a service.